# BindAddress in ssh config on laptop

Tags: linux, ssh, ipv6, privacy

I have a section in my `~/.ssh/config` for connecting to a server via IPv6. But as I have enabled privacy extensions for IPv6 and to avoid my ssh connections being cut I've added BinAddress to that section, so the connections are made from the permanent address.

But the machine is a laptop that I use in different locations, and in more than one I get IPv6, but obviously not the same address, so the BindAddress Directive seems like a bad idea.

How can I make sure ssh/ipv6 connections are always made from a permanent ip, when that ip changes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but what about making a shell function for ssh that compares the config's IP to whatever your current IP is, and updates the config file if required, before then calling 'command ssh'?

Comment: I could do that, I was just wondering if there was a more elegant solution. And I would probably go for just adding `-o 'BindAddress <address>` to `ssh` instead of modifying the config file.

Comment: Privacy extensions won't cut your connection. The old privacy addresses only get removed once you stop using them

Comment: https://home.regit.org/2011/04/ipv6-privacy/ says otherwise, but I was wondering why the kernel wouldn't be able to see that a connection was still alive. I'll try to remove the BindAddress.

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6275#section-4) is a solution developed for the (class of) concern you describe.  It would require an always-accessible home agent (router) as well as support for Mobile IPv6 extension headers on the mobile node and the home agent.

This allows the mobile node to always be accessible at an address on the home network (where 'home' refers to the home of the device--not necessarily your personal residence), in addition to any temporary *care-of* addresses when attached to foreign networks.